# clGetPlatformIDs returns -1001 on intel installation on linux

Tags: c++, linux, opencl

I've installed the Intel OpenCL SDK.  I'm able to find the header and link the library, but none of the functions work.  The very first function called in an OpenCL program, `clGetPlatformIDs()`, returns -1001 - an undefined error code from what I can find.

Other people have gotten the same issue with the Nvidia SDK for OpenCL and fixed it, but I'm finding it hard to get an answer about how to solve the issue with an Intel installation, which has a slightly different setup.

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?
I'm facing same thing on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Please direct your questions about Intel OpenCL SDK to Intel OpenCL Forum: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl

To ensure fast service:

1. Please let us know what Processor, Operating System, Graphics Driver Version, and Tool Version you are using
2. Please state steps to reproduce the issue as precisely as you possibly could
3. Before posting, search the forum to see if someone already answered a similar question

Comment: Also, please make sure that you installed OpenCL driver first :)

Comment: Where can we find OpenCL driver ?